# HTML Form drop down data source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

- I'm aware that this is a topic discussed many times, however I can't find what I'm looking for..

Question: What is the best practice these days as the data source for dynamic drop down boxes, e.g. a user selects a car brand in drop down #1 and an overview of all available models becomes available in drop down #2?

Personally I see three scenario's, and googling doesn't help me find the best practice:

1. Query a database on change of drop down #1, have JS refresh #2 with available models.
2. Query a flatfile (JSON, XML,...), have JS refresh #2 with available models.
3. Load all data at once, have JS manage the selections.

This case is about more or less static data, so a flatfile could be generated every night without problems.

From a performance perspective I consider 3 the least favourite, however between 1 and 2 i'm not sure with today's database optimisations and available bandwidth.

My main concern is end-user experience..

Thanks!

Comment: There are all kinds of valid approaches to this sort of problem, which is best depends on all kinds of factors driven primarily by your circumstances.

Comment: Depending on the amount of data. However for simplicity I would favour outputting all data in the page, either in one dropdown with multi-levels or multiple dropdowns which are shown and hidden based on the first choice

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it depends on each case.

You should always be ready for your data to grow; but you should know **how** it should grow. Also, if your client and server-side logic are well-implemented, querying for a couple hundred registers is not something to take really long.

Stop to do a quick math: query for some names in a database. The DB has 5k records which are well indexed. of these 5k, only 300 satisfy your criteria. So, let's return these 300 names which have an average 50 chars lenght. You have about 15kb of info being transferred. That'd take less than half a second to be received in a common network connection nowadays.

However, for User Experience, having to browse a Drop Down List for a name in three hundred is really not nice. So, it could be a good idea to substitute the Dropdown List for an Auto-complete textbox. Wanna improve the UX even more? Implement a preference logic to know what name the user is most likely to choose (maybe based on his earlier inputs and / or other users' input last days -- the most trending names, you know).

If your main concern is User Experience, you must think like the User who has the Experience. Try to think like this:

- What would be nicer? A Dropdownlist with some hundred entries or a Textbox with an auto-complete function?
- Maybe the autocomplete will leave the user a little clueless, so how about a little list of some examples by the side of the Textbox?
- And even better, what if the examples were actually the ones I'd probably pick?

Coming back to the question, doing queries repetitively can be expensive, so a little caching would be nice. With Html5's SessionStorage and LocalStorage, that's really easy to do. Also, keeping track of some tables in an IndexedDB could also be a good idea, wouldn't it?

The best practice for User Experience is thinking about what will make the user satisfied. Try to make the most out of it.